# Comparing a stored mysql variable with a specific one

Tags: php, session, mysqli

I want to collect the userlevel from the mysql table of the user, which currently logs in and compare it later to a specific one. This is my current code with some explanations.

Both files do have a `session_start();` at the beginning of the whole code, which is working. I know that, because I have a timer running, which destroys the session after a specific period of time and logs the user out.

These lines are inside my loginform. It should gather the user_level of the user logging in `WHERE username='$username'`.

```
    <?php
if(isset($_POST['submitted']))
{ 

    $mysqli = new mysqli('host', 'name', 'psw', 'db');

            if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT user_level FROM users WHERE username='$username'")) {
            $_SESSION['userlevel'] = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
  }
}
```

The `$username'`should be taken form the login form which is written:

```
<label for='username' >Benutzername*:</label><br/>
    <input type='text' name='username' id='username' value='<?php echo $fgmembersite->SafeDisplay('username') ?>' maxlength="50" /><br/>
    <span id='login_username_errorloc' class='error'></span>
```

After that you get redirected to another site, on which is some stuff and a button, that should be displayed. Now I want to compare the user_level, which is stored at the login as `$_SESSION['userlevel']`.
It is written like this:

```
  <?php

    $mysqli = new mysqli('host', 'name', 'psw', 'db');
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
    if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT user_level FROM users WHERE user_level = 1 ")) {

       $r = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
}     

if ($r == $_SESSION['userlevel']){

        $link = 'AdminLayout.php';
        printf ('<a href="' .$link. '">Adminpanel </a>');
      }/* close connection */
    $mysqli->close();
    ?>
```

So it should check my table for the user who has got user_level 1 and compare it with the stored user_level of the logged in user. `if ($result == $_SESSION['userlevel'])` it should display the button.

The problem now is: it doesn't display anything, even if I log in with my user with user_level 1. My question: Is the storage of the user_level wrong or do I have to solve this problem with a completly other solution? My whole code around these lines is working properly and no error occurs.

I know, that php is always processed first from the server - is this relevant? Maybe that it doesn't store the `$username` of my loginform, because the server already run these php lines and doesn't rerun it when the form is submitted?

Thanks for reading this bunch of lines! Hope you get my point.

EDIT (see answers):

Corrected the typo `$_SESSION['userlevel'] = mysqli_fetch_array($result);`

and defined

```
  $r = mysqli_fetch_array($result); }     

if ($r == $_SESSION['userlevel'])
```

It is still not working.

Comment: SQL Injection warning!

Comment: What do you exactly mean with this?

Comment: You are not using prepared queries they you are susceptible to a SQL Injection here `username='$username'` check out this link http://bobby-tables.com/ it will help explain everything.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($r == $_SESSION['userlevel']) {
```

$r is not defined. Use $result instead.

Comment: I tried it with $result before and thought it got doubled in this line `$result = mysqli_fetch_array($result);` so I changed it. with  `$result` it didn't work too!

Comment: `            $_SESSION['userlevel'] = $mysqli_fetch_array($result);` another typo there.

Comment: so I changed it to `$_SESSION['userlevel'] = mysqli_fetch_array($result);`

Answer (score 0):

Change your code in the following way

```
 if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT user_level FROM users WHERE user_level = 1 ")) {

$r = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
}     

if ($r[0]['user_level'] == $_SESSION['userlevel']) {
```

Comment: I tried it with `$result` before and thought it got doubled in this line `$result = mysqli_fetch_array($result);` so I changed it. With `$result` it didn't work too!

Comment: @pr0cz, check my new ans. otherwise print_r($r); and let me know what is the result

Comment: the user_level is defined with 2 automatically at the registration and filled in the table! shall I replace the 0 with 2?

Comment: Okay, then sadly nothing happens. With 2 it got displayed with both accounts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127560/discussion-between-coder-and-pr0cz).